# How to fix graphics driver issue on ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 19.04

I am a complete noob to the whole ubuntu thing. So bear with me.

I have brought an Asus vivobook with Processor      : AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx

It came with windows 10 pre-installed. I dual booted ubuntu 19.04 with it. I don't know if i had graphics drivers installed. So i installed amdgpu-pro. There's where it all went wrong. Upon rebooting after installation i got a black screen(forever). So i checked the internet and uninstalled amdgpu-pro from the recovery screen. Now the ubuntu boots up and everything seems to work fine except that:

1) I can't find the brightness adjust slider on the drop down menu on top right corner.

2) I now only have i option on resolution menu on system settings. Before it had a dozen options.

3) I had setup the experimental display scaling feature. It had been previously working. But now when i select anything other than 100% or 200%, it wont work.

How can i go back to 3rd party graphics driver that were downloaded during ubuntu installation?

Please help

Comment: It worked just fine before the incident. And i'm not that of a gamer at all. I am in it for the developer aspect of it. Using Ubuntu i feel so close to the working of a computer, which my years of Windows experience haven't given me.

Comment: Also i don't think i can reinstall Ubuntu. I have done a lot of customizations to the OS and it will be hell of a lot of work to get the same feel back. Any work around will be highly appreciated.

Comment: usually driver install is something that is acted seconds after the OS finishes installing. I would not have expected this was an old OS. Anyways the whole gamer thing is moot, the point is third party graphics drivers come preinstalled. if you don't want to switch that's ok. Am I to understand that before your driver install scaling & brightness & graphics options worked? on that same ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, i vaguely remember i had raven ridge on graphics info . Now it shows llvmpipe from Xorg foundation